# Get values from database and show it in text view?

Tags: android

```
package as.d.d;

import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class add extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


    Button b1,b2;
    EditText e2,e3;
    TextView t1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add);

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        e3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.AtextView1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);


        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        List<StudentInfo> studentInfo = db.getAllStudentInfo();

        for (StudentInfo cn : studentInfo){

            t1.setText("Id:"+(cn.getID()+1));
        }
   }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        if(v==b2){
            startActivity(new Intent(add.this, FdActivity.class));
        }
        else if(v==b1){

            String s2=e2.getText().toString();
            String s3=e3.getText().toString();

            if(s2.trim().equals("")||s3.trim().equals("")){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Submit Student Information",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }   

            else{
                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
                Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
                db.addContact(new StudentInfo(s2,s3));
                Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
                List<StudentInfo> studentInfo = db.getAllStudentInfo();
                for (StudentInfo cn : studentInfo){
                    t1.setText("Id:"+(cn.getID()+1));
            }}}}}
```

In this add class I am using a Textview for autogenerated student id(numerical(int) and two text field for submit student name and phone number into database by pressing a button.Here the Student Id,Name and phone number submitted succesfully.

In addmark class I use an autocomplete textview for showing the names which I submitted from add class.When I select a name suppose Farhan(which I already submitted into database and the id is 4 and phone number is 99876 stored in database) then I want to see the id and phone number in two textview(TextView t1,t2;)?

```
package as.d.d;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class addmark extends Activity{

    AutoCompleteTextView a1;
    TextView t1,t2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addmark);

        a1=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.amtextView1);
        t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.amtextView2);




        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        final List<StudentInfo> studentInfo = db.getAllStudentInfo();



        final ArrayList<String> s1 = new ArrayList<String>();


        for (StudentInfo cn : studentInfo) {
            s1.add(cn.getName());


        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,s1); 

        a1.setThreshold(1); 
        a1.setAdapter(adapter);



        a1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
}
        });
```

Comment: Can u please explain what is your issue?

Comment: too much code, and not clear what is the actual/expected output or what is not working.

Comment: If I select a Name from autocomplete textview then I want to see the Id and Phone number in two textview?

Comment: update your question clearly instead of adding it in comments

Comment: In add class I submitted Id,name and phone no into database. In addmark class when I select a name from the autocomplete textview(from database which I submitted by add class) I want to set the Id and phone no in two different text view.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all it's a bad idea to select students based on something that is not unique. You want to select the name in your autocomplete text view and then based on that show the phone nr and id. Imagine what would happen if you would have 2 or more students with the same name (which is not excluded). You should populate your autocomplete TV with something (or a combination of somethings) that uniquely define a record in your database.
As for how to achieve this, just verify when your control loses focus and then set the 2 textViews with the values you need.

```
a1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus)
           //set the textViews with the values you need 
    }
});
```

Again, keep in mind that it is NOT recomended to select your id and phone number (both which can be unique identifiers for your DB Table) based on something that can repeat itself in the DB.

Comment: If this is not your answer then explain in more detail what you need. But from what I understood you need to fill 2 `TextViews` based on some info that you extract from your DB into the autocomplete field. What I've told you should cover that, if that's not it, then again, explain IN MORE detail.